# My form submissions results in error 404 page

Tags: reactjs, forms, http-status-code-404

I have a form in my react app that I created using Emailjs. Whenever the form is submitted the user receives an alert (as planned) but after the alert is closed the page refreshes to an error 404 page. How can I redirect it to the home page? Better yet a method for a modal to pop up giving links to other pages within the site? Thanks in advance!

```js
const form = useRef();

    const sendEmail = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

    emailjs.sendForm('sensitiveinfo', 'sensitiveinfo', form.current, 'sensitiveinfo')
        .then(
            () => {
              alert('Message successfully sent!')
              window.location.reload(false)
            },
            () => {
              alert('Failed to send the message, please try again')
            }
          )
          
//This is the opening form tag
<form action='' ref={form} onSubmit={sendEmail}>

//This is the submit button
<input className='submit' type="submit" value="Send" />
```

Comment: where is your btn ?

Comment: Based on your requirements I assume you're using react router dom or something similar for navigation. You can navigate to the required page by using the `useNavigate` hook. For pop ups with links, check out sweet alert2 : https://sweetalert2.github.io/ .

Comment: Updated post to show the submit button

Comment: Check this out.. Just replace your alert with the swal fire. Assuming you're using routing : https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-cloud-0y52rc?file=/src/App.js